# JavaScript: Added EventListener to Element - But when I click on it, the Target is a Nested Element

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener, event-listener, nodelist

I'm having trouble with Event Listeners in Javascript.I add a click Event Listener to a NodeList, but when I click on the element, instead of having the target as one of the elements in the NodeList, it returns the event.target of a nested element instead.

HTML Sample Example:

```
<div class="check-item" id="0-check-item">
    <div class="check-item-top">
        <div class="check-box-title-div">
            <button class="check-box-btn"><span class="material-icons md-36 check-box">&#xE86C;</span></button>
            <h4 class="check-title" id="0-title">Pack Suitcase</h4>
            <div class="check-tag-div"  id="0-tag">
                <span class="check-tag">#Travel</span>
                <span class="check-tag">#Plan</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <h4 class="check-icon" id="0-icon"><span> &#x1F4BC; </span></h4>
    </div>
    <!--Some More Code-->
</div>
```

So I want that when I click on `.check-item` that it returns the id (this example: `0-check-item`)

My JavaScript:

```
let checkItems = document.querySelectorAll(".check-item");

checkItems.forEach((checkItem) =>{
        checkItem.addEventListener("click", changeItemSize);
    })

    function changeItemSize(event) {
        //event.stopPropagation(); <-- doesn't help me
        let itemId = event.target.getAttribute("id");
        console.log("object clicked:",event.target); //Ex. Returns "object clicked: <div class="check-item-top">...</div>
        console.log("item id:",itemId); //Ex. Returns "item id: null"

        //More Code
        }
    }
```

Depends where I click it returns either .check-item-top or .check-tag-div...
I don't want either, I want it to just have the `event.target` of the `.check-item`

Comment: Yes, that's the way it works. If you want the element you added the handler to, use `event.currentTarget` instead.

Comment: This is how it works. It's called event bubbling.